# Lightbox Effect in HTML

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I'm trying to edit my javascript code to enable lightbox when clicked on an image. Presently, it opens the image in another tab. I've searched around online but could not seem to find an answer..

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(function() {
  /* Lets the user click on the images to view them in full resolution. */
  $("img").wrap(function() {
    var link = $('<a/>');
    link.attr('href', $(this).attr('src'));
    link.attr('title', $(this).attr('alt'));
    link.attr('target', '_blank');
    return link;
  });
});
</script>

<img src="img/4_email_a.png" style="border: #A9A9A9 1px solid; width:70%">
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: If you're looking for a Lightbox effect, rather than just opening the image, then I'd recommend just searching for an existing one and using that.  No offence meant, but if you're struggling with the difference between opening an image in the current tab or in a new tab then building a working Lightbox may be a LOT of pointless and difficult work for you.

Comment: just trying to create a rmarkdown html document that allows an user to view images in a lightbox. This has nothing to do with opening an image in a current tab or new tab.

Comment: I know - that's my point exactly.  You've effectively turned an image into a link to an image, which has nothing to do with a Lightbox, which is a vastly larger job.  There are a literal tonne of existing libraries, so unless this is for learning then you're definitely better off using a search engine and just picking one that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a lightbox script like fancybox (https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/), you would just need to add `data-fancybox` attributes for your links, example:

`<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="big_1.jpg"><img src="small_1.jpg"></a>`

It is also possible to make it work without links - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rRVeJW